# what is the behavior of start method inside run method while multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

What happens exactly when we create a new thread and start it in the run method itself? Why do I get different behavior when I declare the thread inside or outside of the run method? Following is the example that I tried:

```
   class MyTDemo implements Runnable {  
     // If I declare t2 here, the program ends after some time
     // Thread t2; 
 public void run()        
  { 
      // If I declare t2 here, the program never ends (until StackOverFlowException)
      Thread t2; 
      System.out.println("in Run");     
      t2 = new Thread(this);     
      try{        
           t2.sleep(5000);   
           t2.start();   
           System.out.println("going out "+t2.isDaemon());       
           t2.sleep(5000);        
           t2.setDaemon(true);           
        }      
      catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());} 
}       
    public static void main(String args[])    
{   
      MyTDemo t = new MyTDemo();     
      Thread t1,t2;    
  t1 = new Thread(t);     
      t1.start();          
      System.out.println("End");        
 }
}
```

Comment: @assylias: The question is incomplete. The OP implies that he's getting different behavior, but doesn't say what that behavior is.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, @assylias.  Editing to clarify.  The code is a bit of a mess.  Note that "unclear" means unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In one case you call `t2.setDaemon(true);` on the **local** `t2` variable **after** the next thread has been started. So you always have at least one non-daemon thread running and that prevents the program from exiting.
- In the other case, you set the the daemon status on the **shared** `t2` variable which allows the program to exit if that statement is executed before the next thread is started, which randomly happens after a few runs.

You could add a `System.out.println("is daemon: " + t2.isDaemon());` after `t2 = new Thread(this);` to better see what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

You are starting threads recursively.
`MyTDemo` is starting in its `run()` method a new `MyTDemo` thread.

Comment: But what about the difference  in behavior  when t2 is declared in run and outside run? its behavior changed . That i have commented..

Comment: That is the obvious reason for when `t2` is a local variable but does not explain the behaviour with a shared variable.

Comment: If t2 is started recursively, is it possible that it is starting with a same identifier "t2" ? Because as I know a thread can be started only once at all